# Nativescript : : error TS2307: Cannot find module 'image-asset'

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Android API21
tns 2.3.0

I'm trying to implement a camera component using [nativescript-sdk-examples-ng](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/camera)

After implementing the code, I get this error on running the app -

> tns livesync ios --device  7a3c131309432ebae1a483f134ec8a4f8cdeecf4 --watch
>
> Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the provided index or identifier.
>   Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/mohit/work/Mobile/native/finly-ng/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
>   Found peer TypeScript 2.0.3
>   app/pages/expensephoto/expense-photo.component.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'image-asset'.
>
> node_modules/nativescript-camera/nativescript-camera.d.ts(1,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'image-asset'.
>
> TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 1

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Hi moaglee, could you provide more info about the device you are deploying nativescript-sdk-examples-ng. I tested it on iOS and Android device and everything work as expected. In the mean time, try to remove `node_modules` `platforms` and `hooks` folders. Clean cache using `npm cache clear` and try to build it again `tns run <platform_name>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample app you are referring is using the tns-core-modules@next where **image-asset** module is present. This module will be officially released with NativeScript 2.4.0 which is expected in a matter of days.

Meanwhile, if you want to experiment with this and other non-released features you can install the @next of tns-core-modules like this.

```
tns plugin remove tns-core-modules
tns plugin add tns-core-modules@next
```

Now your application will have access to image-asset.